# How to get name of folder for Shell Script in Automator?

Tags: macos, terminal, applescript, automator

I'm using the newest version of macOS Monterey.

Sometimes I have to merge/combine all files that are in a specific folder into one txt file.

I currently do that by typing this in Terminal:

```
cd /Users/my_name/Desktop/test_folder ; cat * >merged.txt
```

This will merge/combine all files in folder `test_folder` into one file called `merged.txt`. The file `merged.txt` will get saved into the folder `test_folder`.

Every time I need this I have to open Terminal copy/paste the command and replace `test_folder` with the right folder name, since it's not always the same.

I want to make this easier by just make a right click on a folder, go to Quick Actions and select e.g. `Merge all files` to merge/combine all files inside the folder I just clicked on.

But I stuck at getting the folder name. How can I dynamically get the folder name and path I clicked on to start this Quick Action instead of the hard coded `/Users/my_name/Desktop/test_folder`?

Or, is there another and easier solution?

This is what I have so far:

[image: Automator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn’t do this with AppleScript, especially if all it’s ultimately doing is calling out to a shell script.

Stick with the **Run Shell Script** action except change the option for passing the input *`as arguments`* rather than *`to stdin`*.

The folders selected in Finder will then be available to your script via `$@`, so you can do something like:

```
for d in "$@"; do
    cat "$d"/* > "$d/merged.txt"
    open -R "$d/merged.txt"
done 2>/dev/null
```

This loops through the selected directories and concatenates the files to `merged.txt` in the respective directory.  The `open -R` line reveals the `merged.txt` file in Finder.

Errors are written to `/dev/null`, i.e. discarded, as `cat` will throw an error if any of the directories, themselves, contain directories.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a `Run Shell Script` to your workflow, try adding a `Run AppleScript` command instead.  Copy this following AppleScript code to the `Run AppleScript` command.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    try
        do shell script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of input & " && cat *.txt > merged.txt"
    on error
        try
            do shell script "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of input & " && rm merged.txt"
        end try
    end try
end run
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That seems to work. But for some reason it sometimes works and sometimes it's running for minutes without doing anything. Any idea why?